# Hosted dedicated server with multiple IPs assigned to subdomains

Tags: server, dedicated

I'm currently looking for a hosted server solution which is able to provide with:

- Apache or Nginx engine with PHP and MySQL support;
- multiple IPs (50 and more);
- possibility to edit PTR record, in a way every IP will point to different sub-domains of a single main domain (e.g., 1.2.3.4 - sub1.domain.com, 1.2.3.5 - sub2.domain.com,. 1.2.3.6 - sub3.domain.com);

So, perfectly, that should be a bunch of web servers running sub-domains on different IPs (IPs' subnet level doesn't matter).

Any recommendations?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for an IaaS? Then you Amazon Web services should be what you want. Let me know if IaaS is what you want and I can tell you what AWS services will help you.

Comment: Well, I'd rather want to get just a clean Linux-based server with root access. But AWS may work too, as far as I'm looking for various solutions. So, if you provide me with details I will really appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS should be able to provide what you want. In AWS

1. You can bring up EC2 Instance with LAMP AMIs which will provide
   you with the software you are looking for.
2. Each EC2 instance can
   have multiple private IPs (each private IP can be mapped to an
   elastic IP which are public). The following link explains exactly
   what you want:
   http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/07/06/multiple-ip-addresses-for-amazon-ec2-instances-in-amazon-vpc/
3. Finally using AWS Route 53 Service you can direct each subdomain to
   each of your public IPs using a-name records. Of course I would
   recommend creating Amazon Load balancers and then using CNAME
   records to direct traffic to these Load balancers. But its entirely
   upto you how you want to implement it.

And It need not be AWS.. I think any sophisticated IaaS provider like rackspace or PaaS provider like Pivotal CF, Google App Engine etc should be able solve your problem only using different services and concepts.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, appreciate it! I'm on my way to check it right now.